# MinGW make error

Tags: windows, makefile, mingw

**Hello all !**

I'm trying to make [clearskies ioq3 binary](https://github.com/anthonynguyen/ioq3-for-UrbanTerror-4) with `MinGW` but it doesn't work.

Makefile is ts toooo big for this site, so please look at the comment i added, and don't say me "Post it here" because I can't.

log.txt :

```
    make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Brice/Documents/ioq3'

Building Quake3-UrT-Clear in build/release-mingw32-x86:
  PLATFORM: mingw32
  ARCH: x86
  COMPILE_PLATFORM: mingw32
  COMPILE_ARCH: x86
  CC: gcc

  CFLAGS:
    -fno-strict-aliasing
    -w
    -DUSE_CURL=1
    -DCURL_STATICLIB
    -m32
    -DUSE_SQLITE_BANS=1
    -DUSE_SERVER_EXTRAS=1
    -DUSE_AUTH=1
    -DUSE_DEMO_FORMAT_42=1
    -DUSE_LOCAL_HEADERS=1
    -MMD
    -DNDEBUG
    -O3
    -march=i586
    -fomit-frame-pointer
    -falign-loops=2
    -funroll-loops
    -falign-jumps=2
    -falign-functions=2
    -fstrength-reduce

  Output:
    build/release-mingw32-x86/Quake3-UrT-Clear-Ded.x86.exe
    build/release-mingw32-x86/Quake3-UrT-Clear.x86.exe

make[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Brice/Documents/ioq3'
[[34mSERVER[0m] code/win32/win_shared.c
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Brice/Documents/ioq3'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Brice/Documents/ioq3'
```

I used make command directly into the right folder. It works on Linux (Debian 7 and 8) with the same file but Windows not.

I've codeblocks installed (removed cygwin), but my Path is set to `C:\MinGW\bin` I've installed last version of `MinGW` and like all addons in.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Here is a screen capture (for more infos)](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/31/1438222211-error.png)

Comment: [Here is the make file](http://pastebin.com/bLNzUkRR)

Comment: What makefile have you used ? What command have you used to build?

Comment: You need to provide __much__ more complete detail of your problem, _right here in the question_; links to ephemeral off-site resources, such as samples on pastebin, really don't make the grade.

Comment: Makefile is too big for this site, i've reached the double of char limit. Sorry for the log, i'll remember next time. I don't know other sites to post directly readable text. And as I know, files on pastebin don't die in 2 days uh ? Really ? I'm asking help, i'm giving you all, because I can't put in here and you say that. That's not very nice I think. Thanks for -1, it's cool.

Comment: "Accès refusé" (access denied) / "Fichier introuvable" (file not found) -- if my French (?) doesn't fail me completely, you have a problem with your access permissions. That's most likely unrelated to the Makefile. And why did I have to manually copy those error messages out of a screenshot? Really? "It does not work" indeed.

Comment: I tried to change permissions with Windows Explorer but doens't work. I'm on Windows 7, i'm more a linux user than this... whatever. Maybe must I change permissions in command line (if we can) ? I also tried with another computer, amd64 and Windows 8 this time and it said me the same thing "Access denied". I really don't get the point. Searched on Internet all issues and tried them all, restarted many times my computer and tried to give permissions, i don't know what other thing i used, i can give you website of non-working answers if you want.

Comment: "_Makefile is too big for this site_". Then you need to reduce the scale of the problem ... you should have reduced it to a MCVE (SSCCE) already, and ___that___ should, by definition, be small enough to post directly. Who knows: if you'd done what you should have done in the first place, you might even have identified the cause of the problem, before you even needed to ask.

Comment: I don't understand what you say, i'm noob. Stop annoying me, ty. I'm trying to do my best, and you are agressive with me. Everybody is not like you sorry. It was the first time I posted here, I thought I did good things, you're judging me and it's not very nice. Discussion ended "pr0". Bye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to read carefully the **README**. It says:

> For Windows, using MinGW
>     1. Download and install MinGW and MSys from http://www.mingw.org/.
>     2. Download http://www.libsdl.org/extras/win32/common/directx-devel.tar.gz
>        and untar it into your MinGW directory (usually C:\MinGW).
>     3. Open an MSys terminal, and follow the instructions for compiling on *nix.

copy the files from the **directx-devel.tar.gz** to the msys `lib` and `include` folder.

Comment: Ok, i'm surely dumb. Thanks for the help... ><